# Eager loading ruby modules in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I am attempting to eager-load various ruby files. It is my understanding that this should allow the classes defined in those modules to be called elsewhere in the application without needing to use "require 'filename'" before the call. The source files are stored in the 'lib' directory, which has been added to the page_load_paths with the following line in gps_monitor/application.rb

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("lib")
```

A stripped-down version of the file I'm trying to use is in gps_monitor/lib/production_key_generator.rb

```
require "rails/generators"

module Rails
  module Generators
    class ProductionKeyGenerator < Base # :nodoc:
      
      def self.hello
        "In Hello"
      end
      
      def initialize
        @key = "secret-key"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I then invoke the rails console and attempt to access the class...

```
sol:gps_monitor sjf$ rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 68735
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.4.1)
irb(main):001:0> res = Rails::Generators::ProductionKeyGenerator.new
(irb):1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Rails::Generators (NameError)
Did you mean?  Enumerator
irb(main):002:0> require 'production_key_generator'
/Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:25:in `on_file_autoloaded': expected file /Users/sjf/TickProjectNG/tick_playbook/apps/gps_monitor/lib/production_key_generator.rb to define constant ProductionKeyGenerator, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)
irb(main):003:0> res = Rails::Generators::ProductionKeyGenerator.new
=> #<Rails::Generators::ProductionKeyGenerator:0x00007ff65fc73b18 @key="secret-key">
irb(main):004:0>
```

The first attempt issued the error "uninitialized constant Rails::Generators (NameError)". So apparently the file was not eager-loaded as suspected.

So I tried requiring the file, resulting in a message stating that the file did not contain the class that it obviously does contain.

However, attempting to access the class after the 'require' was successful.

I suspect what's happening is that the eager-load is failing due to the error message, but once manually required, could then access the class.

So why is it telling me that the named file does not contain the named class?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the file that defines Rails::Generators::ProductionKeyGenerator needs to be in the folder "lib/rails/generators" -- not just "lib"

The error message was correct. "gps_monitor/lib/production_key_generator.rb to define constant ProductionKeyGenerator, but didn't"

It didn't define "ProductionKeyGenerator", it defined Rails::Generators::ProductionKeyGenerator. So it needed to be in "lib/rails/generators" to define the proper class.

Easy once you see it!